# Function Error after WP Upgrade to 3.9.1

Tags: plugins, errors

Following the update to WP 3.9.1 and MySQL I am getting the following error on a site:

> Strict Standards: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a
>   valid callback, non-static method dc_jqverticalmegamenu::header()
>   should not be called statically in
>   /home/xyzsite/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 470

The reference is to this [plugin](http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/wordpress-plugins/wordpress-plugin-jquery-vertical-mega-menu-widget/). A quick search shows about 82 pages out there with the same error, but no reference to a solution. I would appreciate some guidance on resolving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should contact the plugin author, because plugin support is generally off topic on this site.

But ... I got curious, peeked into the plugin code and found this line:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', array('dc_jqverticalmegamenu', 'header') );
```

where the `header()` method is assumed *static*, but it's not:

```
function header(){
    // ...
}
```

That's why this strict notice pops up.

The plugin creates an instance of the class through:

```
  // Initialize the plugin.
 $dcjqverticalmegamenu = new dc_jqverticalmegamenu();
```

so you should instead try:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', array( $this, 'header') );
```

and similar for the other static calls.

Comment: My kind friend, birgire, thank you for taking the time to address an off-topic issue - which really has been a show-stopper for the site. Your solution was spot on. In addition I have contacted the plugin author. Thank you again for your assistance.